# New screen for my laptop

Tags: laptop, display

I've broken screen (15") of my laptop (Medion WID 4000 Notebook pc (MD 41205) ) and I've a question.
What does require replacement for this? Has it to be the same model or it only depends on size or resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be same size/aspect ratio (e.g. 15" square or widescreen), but apart from that, there isn't really any difference (unless your laptop is very old). (Just make sure you don't get a LED/different technology).

As for resolution, it doesn't have to be the same, but it is recommended.

The reason for this is that the cable that goes from the mainboard to the screen is pretty much the same as a standard VGA/DVI cable, you can have any resolution monitor but if the graphics card is not powerful enough for it, you may have problems.... But you may not, I have never had a problem in the few times I have increased resolution, I just know it is not recommended.

Comment: What would happen if you got an LED screen if you originally had an LCD one? Wouldn't you save much more power consumption? Or would it just not be compatible?

Comment: To be honest, I am not 100% sure, I usually just replace the old screen with a new one, and reconnect all the components. As far as I know, an LED screen does not need the inverter, so I have no idea what will happen with that or if it requires a different power cable (I have only replaced a LED screen once and I really don't remember). Sorry I can't be more help, but as I said, like for like is safer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be hard pushed to find a economically viable replacement.

Personally, I would consider either using an external monitor with the laptop, or replacing it entirely / recycling it to be some sort of router or server.